# Custom Input[type="submit"] style not working with jquerymobile button

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I want to use my custom style on input[type="submit"] button with jquerymobiles button but it is not working.
My html code is:

```
<input type="submit"  value="Button name">
```

My css code is:

```
input[type="submit"]
{
    border:1px solid red;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:helvetica;
    color:red;
    background:url(../images/btn_hover.png) repeat-x;
}
```

Same style applies when I use following html code:

```
<a href="#" class="selected_btn" data-role="button">Button name</a>
```

Comment: what is the css for `.selected_btn`?

Comment: inspect it with the developer tools and see if the style is applied and if yes if it gets overwritten by another style

Comment: @Dipesh, same style for .selected_btn

Comment: @pfied, class it not applying

Comment: @Prasad you say same style for .selected_btn then obviously it will apply same css try to change some color or anything to see.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### jQuery Mobile >= 1.4

Create a custom class, e.g. `.custom-btn`. Note that to override jQM styles without using `!important`, CSS hierarchy should be respected. `.ui-btn.custom-class` or `.ui-input-btn.custom-class`.

```
.ui-input-btn.custom-btn {
   border:1px solid red;
   text-decoration:none;
   font-family:helvetica;
   color:red;
   background:url(img.png) repeat-x;
}
```

Add a `data-wrapper-class` to `input`. The custom class will be added to `input` wrapping div.

```
<input type="button" data-wrapper-class="custom-btn">
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/w0mzswqd/)**

---

#### jQuery Mobile <= 1.3

`Input` button is wrapped by a DIV with class `ui-btn`. You need to select that div and the `input[type="submit"]`. Using `!important` is essential to override Jquery Mobile styles.

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/SkKVX/)

```
div.ui-btn, input[type="submit"] {
 border:1px solid red !important;
 text-decoration:none !important;
 font-family:helvetica !important;
 color:red !important;
 background:url(../images/btn_hover.png) repeat-x !important;
}
```

Comment: Even though this is an old post its important to note you should not use !important, Try accessing further up the family tree. Like form input[type="submit"]. Otherwise you will have one hell of a time updating your css at a later point.
http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: @MrBandersnatch thanks for the note. In JQM you have two choices to override default styles, either by adding `!important` or add custom classes after page is created. This solution removes unwanted extra styles, when you change your mind, you can find them easily :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assume you cannot get css working for your button using anchor tag. So you need to override the css styles which are being overwritten by other elements using `!important` property.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="selected_btn" data-role="button">Button name</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.selected_btn
{
    border:1px solid red;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:helvetica;
    color:red !important;            
    background:url('http://www.lessardstephens.com/layout/images/slideshow_big.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gs6sv/)**