# jQuery Mobile framework - custom image for submit button

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to use an image for the submit button, but the following code does not work:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" data-role="none" class="loginSubmit" />
```

css:

```
.loginSubmit {background: url("images/submit.png") no-repeat   scroll transparent; display:block;height:54px;}
```

Same code works with the a tag.

```
 <a data-theme="" id="btnSubmit" class="loginSubmit" />
```

Tried the solution suggested in [Custom Input[type="submit"] style not working with jquerymobile button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676447/custom-inputtype-submit-style-not-working-with-jquerymobile-button) but it does not work either. I am using the latest version of jQuery mobile.

Comment: Have you added `!important` after each property in CSS? Add `data-role=button`.

Comment: Check this http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/fkzhz/ without the need to add `data-role=button`

Comment: Can you use an image with text? Strangely the background color seems to be updated, but not the text.

Comment: The image is gradient blue. The text us red, although I removed `!important`.

Comment: Needed to put a height and a width. Working now.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid JQuery mobile overriding styling, add `data-enhance="false"` to the element:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="loginSubmit" data-enhance="false" />
```