# How can I Resize the text Inputs in jquerymobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I'm programing a Responsive web site for Desktops, Tablets and smarthphones, I'm using html, classic asp, jquery and jquery mobile, the problem I'm having now is when try to put a form, the texts input always has the same size, they don't auto-resize when I resize the browser window. So I want to know how can I do to make auto resize inputs in jquerymobile css.

Comment: `.ui-input-text { width: 50%; }` 50% for example.

Comment: By default jQM text inputs do resize with the browser, see the demos: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/textinput/. Perhaps you can show us your HTML markup which is not resizing?

Comment: @Omar .ui-input-text { width: 50%; } is ok for the text inside the box, but I mean to resize all the box of the input, not just the text inside the box

Comment: `.ui-input-text` is a class added to `div` wrapping `input`. Any input type is wrapped in a div with `.ui-input-text` except for search input. If you want to override default `height` & `width`, change CSS properties of `.ui-input-text` or create a custom class as in this answer (jQM >= 1.4) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676447/custom-inputtype-submit-style-not-working-with-jquerymobile-button/15678288#15678288

Comment: Have you tried Flexbox css properties?

Comment: Why is this tagged `juery-ui`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys the problem were with style of the form validation that comes with the examples of jqueryvalidation

```
<style>
    #signupForm {
        <!-- width: 670px; -->
    }
    #signupForm label.error {
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: auto;
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
```